# Don't know what's wrong with the scanf function

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm trying to get 2 integers from the user input by `scanf` function and use `printf` to print out that input. Somehow, I can't print out the 2nd integer. What have I missed here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned long long int x = 0, y = 0;
    printf("The first integer: ");
    scanf("%llu", &x);
    printf("x is %llu\n", x);
    printf("The second integer: ");
    scanf("%llu\n", &y);
    printf("y is %llu", y);
}
```

I tried to run the code from the `printf("The second integer: ")` only and the program couldn't print out the user input for `y` as expected.

Comment: Check the format string in the second `scanf`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, `%u` automatically consumes leading whitespace. The problem is the newline at the end of the second format.

Comment: You are also missing a `\n` at the end in the last `printf`. Make it `printf("y is %llu\n", y);`

Comment: Please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Answer (score 1):

In `scanf("%llu\n", &y);`, `%llu` tells `scanf` to match an optionally signed decimal integer and convert it to an `unsigned long long int`. Then the `\n` tells `scanf` to “[read] input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read” (C 2018 7.21.6.1 5). So `scanf` reads from input. Likely, the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, generating a new-line character in the input stream, and `scanf` read that.

But that is not a non-white-space character, so `scanf` continues reading. At this point, the terminal is sitting with input pending, waiting for the user to type something. If the user types a non-white-space character, `scanf` will see that and complete the `\n` part of the format. Otherwise, `scanf` continues waiting for more input.

Remove the `\n`; change the code to `scanf("%llu", &y);`. Then `scanf` will return when it sees the integer match is complete.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the return value of `scanf`.